# Bootsrap Menu Spry Mobile broken on iPhone 4

Tags: html, css, iphone, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

So I am working on a project and am using Bootstraps menu collapse elements. However, on the iPhone, my code does something like what's pictured here.

[image]

I have no idea how to get around it and fix it. It works great on the iPhone 5 and iPhone 6 and beyond but only breaks on the iPhone 4. Emulators are not reliable in this sense.

[Here is my codepen.](http://codepen.io/ishio/pen/EzClb)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" data-spy="scroll">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
       <div class="row">
        <a class="navbar-brand col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-6" href="body"><img src="http://bowhunting.com/resources/images/logo.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Rhino Group Logo"></a>
        <div class="col-xs-1 col-xs-offset-1 visible-xs phone text-center"><a href="tel:+18475158000"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></a></div>
        <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navigation-bar" class="navbar-toggle collapsed col-xs-2">
          <span class="sr-only"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse pull-right" id="navigation-bar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="caps"><a href="#Services">services</a></li>
          <li class="caps"><a href="#Portfolio">portfolio</a></li>
          <li class="caps"><a href="#Contact">contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: [Using `col-*` classes that aren't children of a `row` doesn't make sense.](https://github.com/twbs/bootlint/wiki/E014)

Comment: FWIW, see http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-brand-image

Comment: I loooked into that, and have made the adjustments where the row comes before the `col-*` classes, however, it still makes no difference.

Comment: I played around with it, and got no where. It still does it only on the iPhone 3GS or iPhone 4. I don't know if there's something special about it?